# What was the significance of the scene where a few girls are enjoying their new home?

Tags: plot-explanation, grave-of-the-fireflies

In *Grave of the Fireflies* a scene immediately follows after Seita buys charcoal for his sister's cremation (at 1:19:57 to 1:20:19). In the scene a few girls are enjoying their new home and a man dressed in soldiers uniform is shown.

What does that scene signify at that point? Can anyone throw some light?